# Mysql count the different id's of the foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

jobs:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| id | title | slug | 
-------------------------------------------------------
```

employments:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| id | job_type| 
-------------------------------------------------------
```

applications:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| id | job_opening_id| application_state_id| 
-------------------------------------------------------
```

application_states

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| id | name| 
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to create a query that counts the different application_state_id's

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| j.title| j.slug| e.job_type | candidates | hired
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the query that i have at the moment:

```
SELECT
  j.title,
  j.slug,
  e.job_type,
  count(a1.application_state_id) as candidates,
  count(a2.application_state_id) as hired
FROM
  jobs AS j
INNER JOIN employments AS e ON j.employment_id = e.id
LEFT JOIN applications AS a1 ON a1.job_opening_id = job_openings.id
LEFT JOIN application_states AS as ON as.id = a1.application_state_id
LEFT JOIN applications AS a2 ON a2.job_opening_id = j.id AND a2.application_state_id = 1
GROUP BY 
  a1.application_state_id,
  a2.application_state_id,
  j.id,
  j.title,
  j.slug
```

I thought i could create 2 joins and set the application_state_id, but all that does is count records double.
What do i need to change in this query? I hope someone can help me.

Comment: It would be better of you could provide sample data and expected output as `formatted text`. Also use: https://www.db-fiddle.com

Comment: you need to identify which table is doublling records first :) after that you need to think about what you need to do

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. Forpas gave me the right query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide sample data, but as I see from your code 
you are joining the table `applications` twice, 
so by the 1st to get the total number of candidates
and by the 2nd to get the total number of hired candidates.
 
I think you can drop the 2nd join and do conditional counting to get the total number of hired candidates. 
Also: 
the select statement must include the columns that you group by and any aggregated columns 
and I don't see why you need to join to the `application_states` table.
Try this:

```
SELECT
  j.title,
  j.slug,
  e.job_type,
  count(a.application_state_id) as candidates,
  sum(case when a.application_state_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as hired
FROM 
  jobs AS j INNER JOIN employments AS e ON j.employment_id = e.id
  LEFT JOIN applications AS a ON a.job_opening_id = job_openings.id
GROUP BY 
  j.title,
  j.slug,
  e.job_type
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)